# How to refer a env variable in a docker compose as part of volumes creation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker compose, is there any possibility to use env variable to instead direct values.

`volumes:
  - /opt:$$VARIABLE`

**ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:**

please let me know is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Docker compose support environment variables out of the box but volumes must have an absolute path.

Export variable -

```
$ export VARIABLE=vijay
```

Change in compose -

```
volumes:
  - /opt:/home/${VARIABLE}
```

Comment: it is not working, however i am using env file to do inject variables to access. It seems to be volumes is expecting absolute path to specify.!

Comment: Yes, variables will expand but you need to specify absolute path, have updated the answer.